# I was trying to find the sum and average of 3 inputs and use call by reference to do it

Tags: c

#code to find sum and average#

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function prototype

void sum_n_avg(double n1,double n2, double n3,double *sum, double *average);
int main()
{
    double s, avg, one, two,three; // declare my values

    printf("enter 3 numbers---> ");

    scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&one,&two,&three);

  sum_n_avg(&s,&avg);

       printf("the sum of the numbers is %lf\n the average of the numbers is ",s, avg);

return 0;
}

void sum_n_avg(double n1,double n2, double n3, double *sum, double *average)
{

  *sum = n1 + n2 + n3;


  *average= (*sum)/3;


}
```

#I get error messages and I do not know what it means or how to fix it #

```
 error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'sum_n_avg'
```

#error occurs when I call my function#

Comment: C doesn't have "call by reference". Call-by-reference semantics is simulated by explicit use of pointers, as you're doing.  The pointers are being passed using call-by-value discipline.

Comment: You forgot to specify n1, b2 and n3. Maybe this is what you wanted: `sum_n_avg(one, two, three, &s,&avg);`

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `sum_n_avg` to take three floats followed by two pointers to float.

You're calling it with two pointers to floats — the incompatible type for argument 1 (a pointer to float rather than an actual float) should be just one of the errors you receive.

You probably wanted:

```
sum_n_avg(one, two, three, &s, &avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you :

```
void somme(double n1,double n2, double n3,double *k,double *l)
{
    *k=n1+n2+n3;
    *l=*k/3;
}

int main()
{
    double s1=0, s2=0, one=0, two=0,three=0; 
    
    printf("enter 3 numbers---> ");

    scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&one,&two,&three);

    somme(one,two,three,&s1,&s2);
    //s1=one+two+three;
    //s2=s1/3; 

    printf("\nthe sum of the numbers is %f and the average of the numbers is %f\n",s1, s2);
return 0;
}
```